# Difficulties changing text indentation within document

Tags: koma-script, changepage

I'm trying to have some part of the document visually offset from the rest by indenting it (i.e. adding a wider outer margin).

The following MWE will fail to compile:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{changepage}

\begin{document}
\begin{adjustwidth}{4em}{0em}
% Remove comment sign to get it to compile ...
\paragraph{Hello World} Too lazy for lipsum ...
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{document}
```

with error

```
LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.7 \end{addmargin}
```

however, removing the comment symbol will produce (the expected) output. I've also attempted the effect using the `quotation` and `addmargin` (from KOMA) environments.

**But** I want to start directly with a `\paragraph` without adding text first. I'm not really sure what could be causing this, hence, I'm posting here.

Can this be fixed somehow? *Or*, if that is not possible, how can the same effect (changing the margin, starting a `\paragraph` at the start of the new block) be achieved? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

Wrap the text inside a `minipage` because you are interested in horizontal alignment here.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{changepage}    
\begin{document}

\begin{adjustwidth}{4em}{0em}
% Remove comment sign to get it to compile ...
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\paragraph{Hello World} Too lazy for lipsum ...
\end{minipage}
\end{adjustwidth}

\end{document}
```

Another simple option which supports page-breaks is adding `\makebox[0pt]{}` like this:

```
\begin{adjustwidth}{4em}{0em}\makebox[0pt]{}
% Remove comment sign to get it to compile ...
\paragraph{Hello World} Too lazy for lipsum ...
\end{adjustwidth}
```

Comment: There's a problem in case it is at the bottom of a page…

Answer (score 3):

Add just this, which can break across pages:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{adjustwidth}{4em}{0em}
\leavevmode\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\paragraph{Hello World}\lipsum[2]
\end{adjustwidth}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I believe there's a dot added by mistake (after `\vspace{-\baselineskip}`).  I indeed require page-breaks. Since you also commented on the other answer, are there any advantages / disadvantages I should be aware of using this solution rather than the `\makebox` solution? As far as I understand a box-creation command implicitly leaves vmode, hence, I'm really asking whether adding the empty box (as is done by the other answer) is somehow helpful.

Comment: In practice, as far as I know, it is equivalent to  `\makebox{}`or `\leavevmode`. My comment was about the use of `minipage`, which cannot break across pages. (B.t.w., I removed the spurious dot).